# design: low voltage clamp circuit (0-200mV)

Tags: voltage-clipping, diode-clamp, precision-rectifier

I need a active safety circuit to clamp voltages to the range of 0-200mV, independent of temperature and very precisely. 
I have simulated, using TINA-TI, 4 precision clamps in series to do this, see design below:
the first two precision clamps ensures the lower clamp voltage and the last two ensures the top clamp voltage. There is an offset for some reason if the buffer is not included.
[image: clamp circuit updated]

However, this is a very component heavy design, and I'm wondering if there is a simpler method? Thanks for reading.

Edit: Ideally I'd like the full swing (0-200mV) with precision to 0.001V. The input will come from a DAQ with -10~10V swing. Also, the load is around 50 ohms.

Comment: 200mV in the title, 0.2mV in the detail - which is it?

Comment: oops! my bad Andy. It is 200mV.

Comment: Yeah I though you meant that hence my amendment in my answer.

Comment: So what's the maximum voltage that you hope to clamp? I'm not asking for the maximum of the range you want to clamp to.  Is the max conceivable input voltage +/-1V as in your graph?

Comment: @RespawnedFluff thanks for the reminder. The input will come from a DAQ with either 0~5v or -10~10V capability (Labjack U3 +analog extension: https://labjack.com/accessories/ljtick-dac).

Comment: Your first and last sections are very strange. Do you really intend to have the - inputs grounded?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Hi Beast. The first two opamps have a grounded input to cut negative voltages. The last two are tied to a 200mV reference.

Comment: No, I mean that, with the - input grounded rather than the + input, the op amps will operate with positive feedback, and will not operate as rectifiers.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I see. Thank you for pointing that out. I'll change it in the schematic.

Comment: OK, now do the right-hand one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> low voltage clamp circuit (0-200mV)

I'd amplify the input signal so that the new desired clamping levels were 0V and 5V. Then I'd use a rail to rail amplifier running on a 0V and 5V supply. Then I'd attenuate the output by 25 so that 5v became 0.2V and 0V remained at 0V.

If the frequency isn't too high, a simple R2R op-amp should work nicely but the devil's in the detail so maybe a simulation is called for?

Following question amendment I propose this, a precision rectifier: -

[image]

It needs to run from split supply rails but will only produce a positive output i.e. it will "clamp" at 0V. Because the circuit is "inverting", a further inverting amplifier will need to be used before this circuit.

I would also consider using a BJT to aid as a voltage follower in order to drive the load. Maybe like this: -

[image]

Rload could be as low as a few ohms but the important thing is that the op-amp has the BJT (or MOSFET) inside the closed loop thus maintaining regulation on the output. The output should be capable of supplying a fair bit of current but as you only need 0.2/50 mA it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Hi Andy, I took a look at available op amps and the minimum for the negative rail seems to be around 0.8V. This translates to losing control from 0-0.032V at the output. Ideally I'd like the full swing (0-200mV) with precision to 0.001V, but this solution is overall better due to it using only one op-amp and thus have a lower chance of failure. I should also mention that the load is a low impedance of around 50ohms. I'll be simulating soon. Thanks.

Comment: You need a rail to rail op-amp not any old standard op-amp. OPA333 springs to mind as does the AD8605/06/08 - there are plenty that will work but will only probably limit at 50mV of either rail so that's a 2mV accuracy after voltage reduction. Regards the 50 ohm load that's a late new entry!!

Comment: With such a large negative input there will likely be other problems so I suggest using an amplifier with +/- supplies but one that is incapable of producing a negative output voltage. I'll draw something.

Comment: Yes, sorry for adding the load resistance late. I'm thinking of adding a voltage buffer in any case, and a 2V zener. However, safety is quite a concern and I'm trying to figure out the most fail-safe design.

Comment: thanks for the update. The only thing I'm worried about is the reliability and accuracy of hard limiting via the positive supply rail.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the positive rail - you can use a 2.5V precision shunt reference to act as a zener diode - they have a very sharp knee voltage due their dynamic impedance being below 0.5 ohms - LM336-2.5 springs to mind. What operating frequency range is your input signal by the way?

Comment: I see, that's a great solution. Input basically is DC with step changes (DAQ output).

Comment: Should be fine but it's worth doing a little research to find the best 2.5V precision zener clamp with the sharpest knee and lowest dynamic impedance.